# Check if intent can be handle. Didnt work for zxing intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing

i am trying to check if there is any activity, which can handle my intent: "**com.google.zxing.client.android**". Main application, which can handle this is **BarCode Scanner** from ZXing company, but **QR Droid** can do i too.

I am using this:

```
List<ResolveInfo> list =  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
     PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (list.size() == 0) //no activity can handle that
```

and this:

```
Intent test = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("com.google.zxing.client.android"));
if (context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(test, 0) == null) 
    //no activity can handy that
```

Main problem is, if i have only **QR Droid** installed and **BarCode Scanner** dont. Result of this two conditions is true (there isnt any application, which can handle that). But if i run that intent:

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
fragment.startActivityForResult(intentScan, RequestCodes.REQUEST_CODE_SCAN);
```

**QR Droid** application is started. Which is good, but i cant predict that :(
Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing `intent` in the first snippet, which should work since it is how it is supposed to be queried: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#288

I bet you have set a package on `intent` which restricts it.

Check the `intent` you are going to launch.

(PS ZXing is not a company)

Comment: Definition of that 'intent' is:
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 

What do you mean by setting package on intent? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: OK, that is good that you do not call `setPackage()`. Try `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);`. Or try passing your `intentScan`. The `test` Intent is completely wrong. Really you should use the supplied integration code and modify it if needed rather than debug this

Comment: i am using same intent for check and for startActivity.
This is my whole function for check: http://pastebin.com/VrBUp5Gi it says, that "no application found" but it run QR Droid :(